# for loop doesn't finish

Tags: android, imageview

In the code below, which is related to Tic Tac Toe, I write a loop that should iterate for 9 times. But I clicked for more than 9 times and the loop doesn't finish. I can't find any mistake in this code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    images[0]= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
    images[1]= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);
    images[2]= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img3);
    images[3]= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img4);
    images[4]= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img5);
    images[5]= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img6);
    images[6]= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img7);
    images[7]= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img8);
    images[8]= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img9);

    Log.i("LOG", "hiiiii ");
    for (int i=0 ; i<9 ; i++) {
        Log.i("LOG", "in: "+i);
        images[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 ImageView imageview= (ImageView) view;

                 if (playerone)     {

                     cell[0]="o";
                     imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
                 }          
                 else  {imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.z);cell[0]="z";}
              playerone=!playerone;
            }




        });
        Log.i("LOG", "in: "+i);
    }

    if ((images[0]==images[1]&& images[1]==images[2])
     || (images[3]==images[4]&& images[4]==images[5])
     || (images[6]==images[7]&& images[7]==images[8])
     || (images[0]==images[3]&& images[3]==images[6])
     || (images[1]==images[4]&& images[4]==images[7])
     || (images[2]==images[5]&& images[5]==images[8])
     || (images[0]==images[4]&& images[4]==images[7])
     || (images[2]==images[4]&& images[4]==images[6])

            ){Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "winner", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

}
```

}

Comment: I don't know android, but it looks like you've registered 9 listeners on 9 different objects, which will get called no matter how many times you click them, e.g: more than 9 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the `for` loop is already finished once the activity is shown.

What you need to do, is implement a check inside the `OnClickListener` that a click on an already occupied square has no effect. In that case, after 9 clicks, there will be no image with which you can interact.

Comment: thanks. I don't have enough  reputation to check your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. You can't *upvote* it, but you can *accept* it.